# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток! При попытке воспроизвести видео с вконтакта столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
    at com.dctua.vkontakte.video.VideoHelper.getVideoPlayerHTML(VideoHelper.java:124)
    at com.dctua.vkontakte.video.VideoHelper.openVideo(VideoHelper.java:30)
```

Код:

```
public class VideoGetting {

public static void openVideo(Video selectedVideo, Activity activity) {
    String playerHTML;
    String error = null;
    try {

        if (selectedVideo.getPlayer() != null) {
            playerHTML = getVideoPlayerHTML(selectedVideo.getPlayer());
            if (playerHTML.contains("youtube")) {
                playerHTML = playerHTML.substring(playerHTML.indexOf("embed") + 6, playerHTML.indexOf("?"));
                playerHTML = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + playerHTML;
                activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(playerHTML)));
            } else if (playerHTML.contains("vimeo")) {
                playerHTML = playerHTML.substring(playerHTML.indexOf("vimeo"), playerHTML.indexOf("?"));
                playerHTML = playerHTML.substring(playerHTML.lastIndexOf("video") + 6);
                playerHTML = "http://vimeo.com/" + playerHTML;
                activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(playerHTML)));
            } else if (playerHTML.contains("rutube")) {
                playerHTML = playerHTML.substring(playerHTML.indexOf("video.rutube.ru") + 16, playerHTML.indexOf(",", playerHTML.indexOf("video.rutube.ru")) - 1);
                playerHTML = getRutubeVideoLink(playerHTML);
                activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(playerHTML)));
            } else if (playerHTML.contains("<param name=\"flashvars\"")) {
                String flvString = playerHTML.substring(playerHTML.indexOf("no_flv") + 7, playerHTML.indexOf("&", playerHTML.indexOf("no_flv")));
                if (flvString.equals("1")) {
                    playerHTML = playerHTML.substring(playerHTML.indexOf("<param name=\"flashvars\""),
                            playerHTML.indexOf("</param>", playerHTML.indexOf("<param name=\"flashvars\"")));
                    playerHTML = createVideoUrl(playerHTML);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(playerHTML), "video/mp4");
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                } else if (flvString.equals("0")) {
                    playerHTML = "http://vkontakte.ru/video" + selectedVideo.getOwnerId() + "_" + selectedVideo.getVid();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(playerHTML));
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        error = activity.getResources().getString(R.string.network_error);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        error = activity.getResources().getString(R.string.network_error);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (error != null) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

private static String createVideoUrl(String flashVars) {
    String urlString;
    urlString = flashVars.substring(flashVars.indexOf("host") + 5, flashVars.indexOf("&", flashVars.indexOf("host")));
    urlString = urlString + "/u";
    urlString = urlString + flashVars.substring(flashVars.indexOf("uid") + 4, flashVars.indexOf("&", flashVars.indexOf("uid")));
    urlString = urlString + "/video/";
    urlString = urlString + flashVars.substring(flashVars.indexOf("vtag") + 5, flashVars.indexOf("&", flashVars.indexOf("vtag"))) + ".";
    String resolutionString = flashVars.substring(flashVars.indexOf("hd") + 3, flashVars.indexOf("&", flashVars.indexOf("hd")));
    int res = Integer.parseInt(resolutionString);
    switch (res) {
        case 0:
            urlString = urlString + 240;
            break;
        case 2:
            urlString = urlString + 360;
            break;
        case 3:
            urlString = urlString + 480;
            break;
        case 4:
            urlString = urlString + 720;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    urlString = urlString + ".mp4";
    return urlString;
}

public static String getRutubeVideoLink(String videoId) throws IOException {
    String link;
    link = "http://rutube.ru/" + videoId;
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(link);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
    link = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    String ownerId = link.substring(link.indexOf("\n"), link.indexOf(",")).trim();
    link = "http://rutube.ru/tracks/" + ownerId + ".html?v=" + videoId;
    return link;
}

public static String getVideoPlayerHTML(String player) throws org.apache.http.ParseException, IOException {
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(player);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
    return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

}
```

}

Погуглив, пришёл к выводу, что нужно юзать асинктаск, только вопрос: что именно в него помещать? За ответ спасибо.

Comment: всю работу с вебом: запрос, ожидание, буферизацию

Comment: то есть последние два метода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Сначала надо отладить без `AsyncTask` и только потом убирать под асинхронный вызов
2. Проверьте какой конкретно URL посылается плееру, судя по логам проблема в синтаксисе урла. Поставьте логи выводящие урл и все станет ясно